# scipy.optimize.curve_fit is sensitive to function form. What are the rules?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

scipy.optimize.curve_fit works fine with a function but chokes on an equivalent function. Example:

```
def func(x, a, b, c, d):
#   return np.exp(a + b * (c -d * x ) ) # works fine
    return a * np.exp( b * (c -d * x ) ) # gives error
```

The error is in the covariance matrix:

```
params= [ 1.16507769 13.26573913  5.90351144  6.24181411]
cov=
 [[-2.16168732e+13  2.55685110e+12  2.64410274e+11
-1.20320851e+12]
 [ 6.54220223e+12  7.78321447e+11 -7.70863674e+11 
-3.66264006e+11]
 [-1.50943415e+12 -5.12305287e+11  3.25950385e+11  
2.41081648e+11]
 [-3.07864319e+12 -3.66264061e+11  3.62754606e+11  1.72357248e+11]]

C:\Python34\hsf\pandas\sample.py:119: RuntimeWarning: 
invalid value encountered in sqrt
perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))
perr= [ nan 882225.28145113 570920.64728287 415159.3038493 ]
```

The first number in the covariance matrix is supposed to be a Variance, a sum of squares. How can it be Negative???

The version that runs without error gives what looks like an identical graph and

```
params= [ 4.32069414 39.26093245  1.8885566   2.10902333]
cov=
 [[ 3.82867157e+14 -3.12417211e+14  5.27625493e+12  1.67824840e+13]
 [-2.81245333e+14  2.17844627e+14 -3.31542721e+12 -1.17022169e+13]
 [ 3.77680355e+12 -2.52146086e+12  2.50916226e+10  1.35448290e+11]
 [ 1.51079875e+13 -1.17022170e+13  1.78098719e+11  6.28621803e+11]]
perr= [19566991.51220365 14759560.52776919   158403.35405783   792856.73527642]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two redundant parameters.  The version of the function that you say works find is `exp(a + b*(c - d*x))`.   The expression

```
a + b*(c - d*x)
```

can be written

```
a + b*c - b*d*x = A + B*x
```

where `A = a + b*c`, and `B = -b*d`.  So you can simplify your function to `exp(A + B*x)`.   The problem with having too many parameters is that the solution is not isolated--the solution space has the same dimension as the number of redundant parameters.  That leads to the Hessian matrix being singular.  Because of normal numerical imprecision, the Hessian matrix in the redundant case won't be *exactly* singular, but it will be poorly conditioned and near singular.  The covariance matrix is derived from the inverse of the Hessian matrix, so if the Hessian matrix is near singular, the calculation of the covariance is numerically unstable and should not be trusted.

Here is a complete script to demonstrate the issue:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def func(x, a, b, c, d):
    return np.exp(a + b*(c - d*x))


def func2(x, a, b):
    return np.exp(a - b*x)


np.random.seed(8675309)
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 16)
y = (10*np.exp(-0.5*x)*np.random.lognormal(sigma=0.25, size=len(x))
     + 0.5*np.random.rand(len(x)))

p, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)
print("p:", p)
print("pcov:")
print(pcov)
print()

p2, pcov2 = curve_fit(func2, x, y)
print("p2:", p2)
print("pcov2:")
print(pcov2)


plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', label="data")

xx = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)

yy = func(xx, *p)
plt.plot(xx, yy, 'k--', label="4 parameter fit")

yy2 = func2(xx, *p2)
plt.plot(xx, yy2, 'g', linewidth=4, alpha=0.3, label="2 parameter fit")

plt.legend(shadow=True)
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('x')

plt.show()
```

The script generates the following plot:

[image: plot]

Whether we used two parameters or four, `curve_fit` found the same solution.

Here is the printed output of the script:

```
p: [1.15386327 1.18656718 1.09383746 0.47713239]
pcov:
[[-2.43958994e+12 -7.92454940e+12  9.37347302e+12  3.19227931e+12]
 [-3.98689093e+13 -1.05598664e+13  4.33789687e+13  4.25387501e+12]
 [ 3.88631613e+13  1.64330041e+13 -4.79524254e+13 -6.61977557e+12]
 [ 1.60605592e+13  4.25387505e+12 -1.74745310e+13 -1.71360622e+12]]

p2: [2.45177495 0.56614914]
pcov2:
[[0.00143014 0.00077371]
 [0.00077371 0.00130843]]
```

`pcov`, the result from the four parameter fit, is basically garbage.  In this example, *all* the diagonal elements are negative, and the matrix is not symmetric.

`pcov2`, the covariance matrix for the two parameter fit, is fine.

The moral of the story: do not use redundant parameters in your model function if you need to use the covariance matrix returned by `curve_fit`.

---

By the way, as you have already noted, you can rewrite `exp(A + B*x)` as `exp(A)*exp(B*x)`, and then define `C = exp(A)` to express your function as `C*exp(B*x)`.  You can then use the parameters `B` and `C` instead of `A` and `B` in `curve_fit`.  Just be aware that this version allows `C` to be less than or equal to 0, so an answer such as `-2*exp(-3*x)` is possible.  A negative function like that is not possible when you use `exp(A + B*x)`.  To ensure that the two parameterizations have the same possible solutions, you would have to use the `bounds` argument to constrain `C`.

Comment: Thank You. The original version with 'a' inside the exponential, with the redundant parameter, is the one that works fine. In the version with 'a' taken outside the exponential function, I did as you suggested and changed it to 'a * np.exp( bc -d * x  )'. It still fits fine, but I still get the negative variance for 'a' and the resulting sqrt error. So the redundancy does not appear to have been the problem. Also, I want to allow a negative value of 'd' since some of the exponentials are concave upwards and some downwards.

Comment: See my updated answer.  In the case that "works fine", you don't get an error, but how do you know that the results are correct?

Comment: I plot the results and they are a fine fit, certainly nothing pathological.

Comment: OK, but the problem is not with the parameters that were found.  The problem is in the covariance matrix that you are using to estimate the errors.

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data you are fitting?